# How does one define one single Configuration for Big Step and Small Step semantics in Coq?

Tags: coq

I was trying to define the configuration that help a statement/code/program/arithmetic/bool expression, but I found myself having to define one for each type which seems unnecessary. Is it possible to merge all the different cases somehow in Coq?

```
Inductive BigConfig : Type :=
  | B_AExpConf : AExp -> State -> BigConfig
  | B_BExpConf : BExp -> State -> BigConfig
  | B_StmtConf : Statement -> State -> BigConfig
  | B_BlkConf : Block -> State -> BigConfig
  | B_StateConf : State -> BigConfig
  | B_PgmConf : Program -> BigConfig.
```

then I noticed I also had seperate configurations for big and small step. Is it possible to merge them into 1 single configuration?

```
Inductive SmallConfig : Type :=
  | S_AExpConf : AExp -> State -> SmallConfig
  | S_BExpConf : BExp -> State -> SmallConfig
  | S_StmtConf : Statement -> State -> SmallConfig
  | S_BlkConf : Block -> State -> SmallConfig
  | S_PgmConf : Program -> SmallConfig.
```

Comment: `BigConfig` is equivalent to `SmallConfig + State` (with the right component corresponding to `B_StateConf`. That seems close enough.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia in code? I'm still a beginner at Coq and I'm not sure how to translate your natural language to Coq.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, a `BigConfig` is `SmallConfig + State`, meaning, if you define `SmallConfig` as you did:

```
Inductive SmallConfig : Type :=
  | S_AExpConf : AExp -> State -> SmallConfig
  | S_BExpConf : BExp -> State -> SmallConfig
  | S_StmtConf : Statement -> State -> SmallConfig
  | S_BlkConf : Block -> State -> SmallConfig
  | S_PgmConf : Program -> SmallConfig.
```

Then one way to define `BigConfig` is:

```
Definition BigConfig : Type := sum SmallConfig State.
```

Then instead of pattern-matching on `BigConfig` constructors (which don't exist anymore), you have to pattern-match on `sum` (`inl`/`inr`) and `SmallConfig` constructors in the `inl` case.

```
match bconf with
| inl (S_AExpConf a s) => ...
| inl (S_BExpConf b s) => ...
...
| inr s (* this represents B_StateConf *) => ...
end
```